# GL_DEPTH_TEST not work in glsl shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

Recently, I am working with glsl and fbo in a OpenGL framwork. Here are the details:

Glfw and glew are used to build the OpenGL environment.

I render to a  OpenGL window,and also to a fbo (Framebuffer object).

Several render buffers are bind to the fbo, for difference render data, pixels' color, pixels' triangle and vertex id, etc.

A sphere is assigned its texture by "Projected texture" method.

I set `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` before the render loop.

Before each frame I run `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`

Create the FBO:

```
glGenRenderbuffers(1,&m_color_buffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,m_color_buffer);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGBA, WindowWidth, WindowHeight);

//////generate other render buffers////////////

glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,m_fbo);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,
             GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_color_buffer);

//////bind other render buffers////////////

//set the render buffers
GLenum drawBuffers[] = { GL_NONE, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, 
       GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3 };
glDrawBuffers(5, drawBuffers);
```

In the fragment shader:

```
layout( location = 1 ) out vec4 FragColor;
//////////other output variables ///////////////////
void main() {
   vec4 projTexColor = vec4(0.0);
   if( frag.ProjTexCoord.z > 0.0 )
   {
       projTexColor = textureProj( ProjectorTex, frag.ProjTexCoord );
   }
   FragColor = projTexColor;
   /////////write other data/////////////
}
```

RenderBuffer to file:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo);
glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);

GLubyte *m_data = (GLubyte*)malloc(4 * m_width * m_height);
glReadPixels(0, 0, m_width, m_height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_data);
TGAIO::write(m_data,m_width,m_height,"e:/1.tga");
```

Here is result:

Render to OpenGL window:
[image]

When render to fbo:
[image]

It seems that the back part of the sphere appears. And also the front part become fragmented.

So, what's happened ?  I do not declare the output for GL_NONE(OpenGL default render buffer) in fragment shader, how does it get the right data ? It seems that OpenGL is smarter than me, at least. LOL.

Comment: Try to attach a separate texture for depth to the framebuffer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank you, it's work!!!!!